# Implementing pass point protocol

Tags: ieee-802.11

The pass point protocol can it be implemented on the application layer of any  mobile device or does it require compatible wifi routers and access points as well.

Answer (score 1):

It requires devices (access points and mobile devices) which support IEEE 802.11u/Hotspot 2.0. Wi-Fi.org provides a [product finder](http://www.wi-fi.org/product-finder-results?capabilities=1&items=30) which provides a list of certified products. Though not on the certified product list a quick Google reveals Apple iOS 7 supports Hotspot 2.0 as well.

Comment: Robert,so what goes into certifying a device 802.11u ,is there a hardware requirement or could I use an OS like openwrt and add the 802.11u capability and add it to a router or ap that might not be previously 802.11u certified ,is that possible ?

Comment: That could possibly depend on the hardware in question and how much of it's code is in hardware and how much is written into the driver/software. However, while the original question could be viewed as on topic, this comment steers it clearly into software coding/development, which is off topic here.